# ajax delay disrupts order of operations

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is a program that calls ajax to read a value from the header of a http response and set a variable called _ecpop and use that for later operations...

So I defined a variable globally called _ecpop as

```
var _ecpop="";
```

and then here is the ajax call code:

```
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
    _ec_req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    _ec_req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    // make the request
    _ec_req.open("GET", requestString, true);
    // function to deal with response
    _ec_req.onreadystatechange = function()  {
    if (_ec_req.readyState==4)
        {
        if (_ec_req.status==200)
            {
            var respHeaders = _ec_req.getAllResponseHeaders();
            // strip out unnecessary headers
            respHeaders = respHeaders.replace (/\n/g,"|X|");
            var beg = respHeaders.indexOf("ECAcc (");
            _ecpop = respHeaders.substring(beg+7,beg+10);
            //make an if statement here...
            console.log(_ecpop);

            }

        }
    }
    console.log(_ecpop);
```

and the rest of the code uses _ecpop.

The problem is the browser executes the rest of the code with _ecpop="". i.e. first the second console.log(_ecpop); returns empty and then the first  console.log(_ecpop); returns the correct value.

Is there anybody who knows how I can get around it? it is so irritating ...

Thanks,

Amir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX (an acronym for Asyncronous Javascript And XML) is inherently asynchronous. That means that it begins executing when the Javascript engine encounters it in a script, but the rest of the script continues processing without waiting for the AJAX call to complete.

You can circumvent this behavior by instructing your AJAX call to operate synchronously:

```
_ec_req.open("GET", requestString, false);
```

Setting `false` as third parameter of `open()` will provide your requested behavior.

Comment: Please make sure you have cleared your browser's cache to ensure you are using the most recent version of the script. If the problem persists, please post more information about the problem after examining the network request in Firebug console.

Comment: ok here was the problem... I need to call _ec_req.send(null) before the console.log(_ecpop) (not after)... :-)

Comment: Thanks man... what I learned is I need to read every option and their definition before copy-pasting!...